# Flask-Login: login user and redirect to home page after registration

Tags: flask, flask-login

Using flask login, trying to login the user after the user registers.
user_login() works for my login route, however after registration, it redirects to the login route, not the intended home page.  So my question is, can login_user() only work in a 'login' route?

Here is a basic version of what I have now:

```
class User(flask_login.UserMixin):
def __init__(self, userName, email, firstName):
        self.userName = userName
        self.id = email
        self.email = email
        self.firstName = firstName

@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(email):
    """ code to get userdata from database """

    user = User(userName,email,firstName)

    return user

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('register.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        """ code for creating user from form data """
        #create session for user
        user = User(userName,email,firstName)

        flask_login.login_user(user)

        return redirect(url_for('home'))

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')

    elif request.method == 'POST':
       """ code for authorizing a user """

        user = User(userName,email,firstName)

        flask_login.login_user(user)
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('home'))
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/home')
@flask_login.login_required
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

UPDATE:
I wasn't loading my user correctly in my user_loader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you register the user, you're redirecting straight to the `/home` route, which requires the user to be logged-in. But you haven't actually logged them in at this stage, only created the user.

You should add the following in your `/register` route after the user has been created:

```
    flask_login.login_user(user)
```

Comment: O shoot I forgot to add that line in my question text.  -- I have tried with that piece in my actual code, and still to no avail.  However, it should be possible to user login_user in the register route correct?

Comment: Yes, typically when they register you would call login_user to log them in straight away.

Comment: It seems the login_user(user) executes and it redirects from register to home, however I have a login_required() for my home page, and when login_required() fails, it redirects to the login page.  --  So what I have now is 1: I register, 2: redirects me to home 3: fails login_required() 4: redirects me to login -- hopefully this information helps?

Comment: Just checking - when you create the user as part of registering, are you committing the record to the database? And your user_loader method should be retrieving that user from the database, at the moment it looks like it is creating a new user each time?

Comment: I think I may have found it, the user_loader() isnt being called after registration.  However, user_loader() works when its used in the login route.  -- Now I have to figure out how to call the user_loader() when the user is registered.